# ngOnInit not called in tests

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have component that is standalone Angular component. I create it in beforeEach method of test class like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
   await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot(), 
             HttpClientTestingModule],
    }).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;});
```

Then I have few tests. Of course also default one:

```
it('should create', () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

But when I run ng test --code-coverage I see that surprisingly ngOnInit method of this component wasn't called at all. So it's not covered. I don't have this problem with other components. What can cause it?

Comment: `ngOnInit` is part of angular component filecycle, if you want to run the change detection cycle in test you should run `fixutre.detectChanges()` after creating instance of component in beforeEach.

Comment: yeah, that's an answer :) Thank you